# Exo Player on orientation change video is getting started from the beginning and not from the previous position

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to implement a Exoplayer in a baking app, but when the orientation is changed video is getting started from the beginning and not from the previous position.
I tried everything.
I will provide the code, the EXO Player is in StepFragment class.
https://github.com/AhmedHamdan54/iBake